# Remove hours from DateTime XQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

So, I have this expression in XML:

```
<can:interactionDate>2020-06-24T12:42:55</can:interactionDate>
```

And this is the actual xquery:

```
<ser:documentIssuanceDate>{ data($body/.../can:interactionDate) }</ser:documentIssuanceDate>
```

As you can see, it doesnt make any transformations in the field.

I need to send only the date, without the hours.

I'm expecting a result like this:

```
<ser:documentIssuanceDate>2020-06-24</ser:documentIssuanceDate>
```

Is there any methods to do such thing?

Comment: Larissa, what is your XQuery engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "proper" way to do this is using the [date and time processing functions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#dates-times) of XQuery. In your case it is sufficient to parse the string as an `xs:dateTime` and then cast it to an `xs:date`, thereby discarding the time component:

```
<ser:documentIssuanceDate>{ xs:date(xs:dateTime($doc/.../can:interactionDate)) }</ser:documentIssuanceDate>
```

This returns `<ser:documentIssuanceDate>2020-06-24</ser:documentIssuanceDate>` as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this part

```
$body/.../can:interactionDate
```

to

```
$body/.../can:interactionDate/substring-before(.,"T")
```

and see if that works.